# Why $[\sqrt[5]{3} \operatorname{cis}(30^{\circ})]^{10}$ results $237046875 \operatorname{cis}(300^\circ)$ instead of $9\operatorname{cis}(300^\circ)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

$\newcommand{\cis}{\operatorname{cis}}$Complete question is:

Evaluate $\left[ \sqrt[5]{3} \left( \frac{ \sqrt{3}}{2}+ \frac{i}{2} \right) \right]^{10}$

---

My Professor answers this:

$$[\sqrt[5]{3}\cdot \cis(30^\circ)]^{10} = 237046875 \cdot \cis(300^\circ)$$

---

Here is my calculation:

$$[\sqrt[5]{3}\cdot \cis(30^\circ)]^{10} = (\sqrt[5]{3})^{10}\cdot \cis(10\cdot 30^\circ) = 9\cdot \cis(300^\circ)$$

How can $(\sqrt[5]3)^{10}$  become $237046875$?

Comment: $237046875=3\times 5^6 \times13 \times 389$ and I do not see a reasonable way of getting there

Comment: What does "cis" mean?  Does it mean $e^{i30^\circ} = \cos 30^\circ + i \sin 30^\circ$?  I don't have the slightest idea what your professor is doing.

Comment: @fleablood Just checked on Wikipedia, cis(x) is a rather uncommon notation to denote $\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$

Comment: I assume you are using DeMoivre's formula $(rcis\theta)^n =r^ncis(n\theta).$ It seems to me that you are perfectly correct. I've made some computational blunders in my time, but your professor's is a real head-scratcher.

Comment: $$ 237046875 = 3\times 5^6 \times 13 \times 389. $$
The answer that you attribute to your professor makes no sense. $\qquad$

Comment: I can only surmise you professor must have meant some $\sqrt[n] m$ where $(\sqrt[n]m)^{10}=m^{\frac {10}n}$ is some irrational number and he forgot to write down the decimal point.  If for example that was meant to be $\sqrt[4]3$ instead of $\sqrt[5]3$ we'd have $3^{\frac {10}{4}}cis(300) = \sqrt {32}cis(300) = 5.65685cis(300)$.  But what he had in mind.... who knows....  You seem to be correct and none of us can figure out the professor.

Comment: @fleablood : If your MathJax code says `\operatorname{cis}`, that does not only prevent italicization but also results in proper spacing in $5.65685\operatorname{cis}(300).$ The amount of space to the left and right depends on the context, whereas that doesn't happen without `\operatorname{}`. $\qquad$

Comment: @ChrisLeary : $\quad \uparrow\quad$ Similarly with $r\operatorname{cis}\theta. \qquad$

Comment: That may be true but I hardly think it is worth the trouble in a rapid comment limited to 600 characters.